# Convert an org.bson.Document to an org.bson.BasicBSONObject in Java?

Tags: java, bson, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

I have a String in Pentaho Data Integration (PDI) a.k.a. Kettle, in a transformation's UDJC step.
So using Java, I need to take that String which contains JSON from MongoDB, and put it into a BasicBSONObject. (I can use import statements but I can't install things as part of a solution.)

I got the String into an org.bson.Document so it seems like the hard part's over, but I still can't figure out how to convert one type of bson to another here, resulting in an object of type org.bson.BasicBSONObject

This errors out on the last line:

```
import org.bson.Document;
...
String mongoResultString = get(Fields.In, "mongoAsset").getString(r);
Document mongoResultDoc = Document.parse(mongoResultString );
BasicBSONObject mongoResult = (BasicBSONObject) mongoResultDoc;
```

Tried ecosia, google, and searching Stack Overflow.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `BasicDBObject#parse` method in MongoDB Java Driver library, which is most probably present on the classpath of your application. This method, according to the [documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/?com/mongodb/BasicDBObject.html), parses a string in MongoDB Extended JSON format to a BasicDBObject.

You can use it directly and skip the `Document` parsing step.

```
BasicBSONObject mongoResult = BasicDBObject.parse(mongoResultString);
```

Answer (score 2):

After much wasted time with multiple online resources suggesting to use `org.bson.Document` and then they become too busy being BSON evangelists to mention the actual **solution** part... *facepalm* ...I finally found out this is actually quite simple. Parse the String into a JSON and immediately cast to a BasicBSONObject:

```
BasicBSONObject mongoResult = (BasicBSONObject) com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse(mongoResultString);
```

That worked for me because I already know `mongoResultString` is valid JSON because it came straight from Mongo, but otherwise could presumably wrap it in a try block.

Not sure of performance differences or gotchas, but now that I know what to look for, I've also seen evidence of Eugene's solution being workable. (Also shorter. Accepting that as the solution.) Thanks very much!